# How do i make it so a discord bot only replies to me

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How do i make it so the bot only replies to me and says something else when its not me
so when it is me the command below will execute and when it doesn't it will say something along the lines of User not granted permission, it works with roles instead of id but even if i do that i still don't know how to make it say that user not granted permission

```
    if (message.author.id == '447206072684511252');

    if(target) {
        let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'VirginityLevel1️+');
        let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');

        let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

        if (!args[1]) {
            memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
            memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
            message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted.`);
            return
        }
        memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
        memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
        message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`);

        setTimeout(function () {
            memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
            memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
        }, ms(args[1]));
    } else{
        message.channel.send('User not found');
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use a return statement. This will stop your code early and prevent it from doing anything else.

```js
if(message.author.id !== 'your id') return;
//any other code to be run ONLY FOR YOU
```

And to give multiple (specific) people access, do this:

```js
if(['userid1', 'userid2'].includes(message.author.id)) return;
//…
```